# How do I get the only users of a JSON on a certain date?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON with more than 1000 rows.
How do I do for example to list all users only from month 12?

I expect as a result: senders 20, 13 and 18. Sender 4 does not appear because it already exists in month 11

```
[{"recipient":1,"sender":4,"created_at":"2016-11-10","content":"Duis aliquam convallis nunc. Proin at turpis a pede posuere nonummy. Integer non velit. Donec diam neque, vestibulum eget, vulputate ut, ultrices vel, augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec pharetra, magna vestibulum aliquet ultrices, erat tortor sollicitudin mi, sit amet lobortis sapien sapien non mi. Integer ac neque. Duis bibendum. Morbi non quam nec dui luctus rutrum. Nulla tellus. In sagittis dui vel nisl.","is_sender_user":true},
{"recipient":1,"sender":18,"created_at":"2016-12-10","content":"Proin eu mi.","is_sender_user":false},
{"recipient":1,"sender":4,"created_at":"2016-11-20","content":"In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi vestibulum, velit id pretium iaculis, diam erat fermentum justo, nec condimentum neque sapien placerat ante. Nulla justo. Aliquam quis turpis eget elit sodales scelerisque. Mauris sit amet eros. Suspendisse accumsan tortor quis turpis. Sed ante. Vivamus tortor. Duis mattis egestas metus. Aenean fermentum.","is_sender_user":true},
{"recipient":1,"sender":20,"created_at":"2016-12-14","content":"Donec ut dolor.","is_sender_user":true},
{"recipient":1,"sender":13,"created_at":"2016-12-06","content":"Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat. Curabitur gravida nisi at nibh.","is_sender_user":true}]
```

Thank you all.

Comment: *"Sender 4 does not appear because it **already** exists in month 11"* - What do you mean by "already"? Did you mean "only"?

Comment: @nnnnnn He wants senders that are in month 12 but not in any other month.

Comment: @Barmar - Maybe. But the sample input doesn't have any senders with dates in more than one month, hence my asking for clarification. A better sample would include a sender that appears with a December *and* a November date, and a note about whether to include that sender in the results.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I noticed that after I replied, it's not very clear. If he just wants all senders from month 12, it's much simpler.

Comment: Loop over the array and construct an object whose keys are the sender numbers, and values are an array of all the months that they sent a message. When you're done, find all the senders whose array is just `[12]`.

Comment: @Barmar That's it, I want all December users, but they do not exist in November.

Comment: @JoãoPedro Can you fix the example so that it shows users who are in multiple months?

Comment: that's a javascript array, that isn't JSON

Answer (score 1):

Without considering the performance, could this answer solve your problem?

```
// Get invalid Sender's IDs' list
var invalidSenders = array.filter(ele => !ele["created_at"].startsWith("2016-12")).map(ele => ele['sender']);
// Generate new list
var newArray = array.filter(ele => ele["created_at"].startsWith("2016-12") && !invalidSenders.includes(ele['sender']));
// Debug
newArray.forEach(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: This will not remove users that are also in other months.

Comment: @Barmar I see, I'd like to re-post it later

Comment: @choasia Thanks for your response, it manages to remove users from other months, but it repeats the same user multiple times.

Comment: @Barmar the example totally misled me, did I understand the problem correctly now?

Comment: @Barmar Aha, I think you've already given the solution in the comment. Wish my answer made it more clear.

Comment: Your way works as well, and it makes nice use of functional programming, but it will be pretty inefficient for large datasets.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed, invalid senders should be excluded at once during the loop.